# Provide jquery-typeahead working example

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am trying to make the first demo example "Country v1" of jquery-typeahead work from:
http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/

What I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/0akjs4d0/

```
$.typeahead({
  input: '.js-typeahead-country_v1',
  order: "desc",
  source: {
    data: [...]
  },
  callback: {
    onInit: function(node) {
      console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
    }
  }
});
```

I cannot see the list of suggestions at all, even when I type in the input box. Tried on Chrome/FF.

Could anyone help me make it work?

Comment: What part doesn't work? Your Fiddle works fine.

Comment: @putvande do you see the list of suggestions showing up? Tried on Chrome and FF, doesn't show anything for me.

Comment: Are you expecting the list to be displayed before you type inside the box?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu no I am expecting the list to be displayed at all. It doesn't show up at all here, tried on several browsers/machines, do you see the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, adding `minLength:1` to the `options` object makes it work. According to [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md), this is the default value of `minLength`, so it shouldn't be required.

Also note `node.selector` in your `callback` function is `undefined`. You can find the DOM element in the `[0]` property of `node`, since it's a jQuery instance:

```js
$.typeahead({
  input: '.js-typeahead-country_v1',
  minLength:1,
  order: "desc",
  source: {
    data: [...]
  },
  callback: {
    onInit: function(node) {
      console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ', node[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/0akjs4d0/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Follow up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436723/jquery-typeahead-hide-suggestion-box-on-choosing-an-entry