# jquery-typeahead hide suggestion box on choosing an entry

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am playing with the first demo example "Country v1" of jquery-typeahead work from: http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/

```
$.typeahead({
  input: '.js-typeahead-country_v1',
  minLength: 1,
  order: "desc",
  dynamic:true,
  source: {
    data: data
  },
  callback: {
    onInit: function(node) {
      console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qz7dfsku/

I am trying to have the suggestion box disappear when I select one of the choice.

It seems adding dynamic: true breaks it, if I set it to false then it works.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Adding `dynamic:true` seems to make the suggestion box persistent. Is there another, less obvious effect? Because right now you seem to be expecting an option **not** to work. The simple fix is not to use it. By the way, `dynamic` is not documented in [options](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options). From here it looks like a hidden feature and, most times, hidden features are not production ready, meaning in some cases they break stuff.

Comment: You're not looking at the proper doc, it's documented here : http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in 2.10.2.

https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/issues/380

"that's an unwanted behaviour because of an extra request being sent #381 when the item is selected, will patch that asap"

https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/issues/381